# Create a mileage log from google timeline

Tags: google-maps

It would be useful to have a mileage log be created from the google maps timeline. Is there a way to have the data extracted to be able to have a to and from distance, date and times. so far all the apps go forward in time and none of the apps can go back, please, someone write a program that will take the data and put it into a mileage log.